# Playwright typescript cannot find module

Tags: typescript, npm, e2e-testing, playwright, monorepo

I'm trying to implement playwright in my project and somehow playwright is not able to a) resolve path aliases and b) it's not able to resolve some *installed* npm package.

The project structure:

```
.
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── playwright.config.ts
├── src
└── tests
    └── e2e
        └── sign-in.e2e.js
```

Parts of the `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "@/src/*": ["./src/*"]
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar setup/structure to you and mine are configured as so:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "src/*": ["src/*"],
    "tests/*": [tests/*]
  }
},
```

The [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) seems to support this.  I've not seen `@src/*` being used before.